# Laravel Name resolution issue

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I am new to laravel and trying to learn laravel but I am stuck while 
entering a server name in httpd-vhosts.conf I entered this in httpd-vhost.contf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Xampp/htdocs/lsapp/public"
    ServerName   lsapp.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

and in system32 host file :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 lsapp.dev
```

[See the error in homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hQv5.png)

Comment: How you run php and mysql . with xampp ?

Comment: yes i am using Xammp

Answer (score 0):

Use run this command, in project root

```
php artisan serve --host=lsapp.dev --port=80
```

Be sure to stop mysql from xampp , which uses port 80,

Above command require to set `127.0.0.1 lsapp.dev` in your host file, as you did already

If you want to go without command set `DocumentRoot` in `httpd-vhost.contf` as you did already

```
"D:/Xampp/htdocs/lsapp/public"
ServerName   lsapp.dev
```

And in host file

```
127.0.0.1 lsapp.dev
```

And **restart** apache, stop and then start apache to reflect, and hit `lsapp.dev` browser

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost lsapp.dev:80>
  DocumentRoot "D:/Xampp/htdocs/lsapp/public"
  ServerAdmin laravel.dev
  <Directory "D:/Xampp/htdocs/lsapp/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and don't forget the **.htaccess** file in public folder

---

Apache  (from laravel docu...)

The framework ships with a public/.htaccess file that is used to allow URLs without index.php. If you use Apache to serve your Laravel application, be sure to enable the mod_rewrite module.

If the .htaccess file that ships with Laravel does not work with your Apache installation, try this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

If your web host doesn't allow the FollowSymlinks option, try replacing it with  Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch.

Comment: Sir what do you want me to do with the .htaccess file can you kindly tell me ?